# iCal for authenticated users

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, icalendar

I am using the calendar module with its iCal support for Drupal 6. I have made my event type which appears on the iCal feed. However, I want to make the event content type private, so only authenticated users can read it. By doing this they will not show on the iCal feed. Is there any way that I could get the iCal feed to still show these events?

Comment: A feed by nature is public, so it doesn't really make sense to have a feed of private content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with calebthorne that normally a feed is public; I can understand the need of making a feed public for a group of users, and not to the anonymous users.

If the feed is created by a view, then you can change the view, and restrict its access to the users you want.

As you can see in the screenshot, you can restrict the access to the users with a particular permission, or to the users with a specific role (authenticated user is one of them).

[image: Views settings]

Comment: To notice I changed the access setting for the display "feed", not the default display. That means I have overridden the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I would give the [Node Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module a look. I use this module to restrict access to content based on content type. I have never tested whether this works in conjunction with the [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module but it is worth a shot.

Some more details about the [Node Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module (from its project page):

> Nodeaccess is a Drupal access control module which provides view, edit and delete access to nodes. Users with the 'grant node permissions' permission will have a grant tab on node pages which allows them to grant access to that node by user or role. Administrators can set default access controls per content type, and also define which roles are available to grant permissions to on the node grants tab.
>
> The upshot is, this module allows you to do things like 'node 123 can be viewed by authenticated users and edited by admin users and joeuser'. As an added bonus, update and delete permissions are separated, so you can make sure users with edit permissions cannot accidentally delete pages.